# % in pandas invalid literal for float():

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

I tried running a random forest model on my loan data set, I loaded my csv file as a pandas dataframe, and used the variable `loan_amnt`,`int_rate` as my feature, `Loan_status_B` is `1` or `0` as my label.

my dataframe looks like this:

[image: my dataframe looks like this]

```
traning_set = train[['loan_amnt','int_rate','Loan_Status_B']]
features_train = array(traning_set[['loan_amnt','int_rate']])
labels_train = array(traning_set[['Loan_Status_B']])
```

I created a test set in the same way

```
#Random Forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf = clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

pred = clf.predict(features_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print accuracy_score(labels_test, pred)
```

This produced a `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 19.20%`
Has anybody encountered this problem before or knows how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried converting the string percentages to float, by stripping the '%' and then running float()? You can probably use `apply()` or similar for that.

Comment: You should remove the `%` sign before passing it to the function.

Comment: What is this? I don't even see where the % comes into play. Can you post all of your code so we can give you a proper answer?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I read my csv file and try to change the data type of the interest rate (which is object) by using    df['int_rate'].astype(float)   , but it shows the same error  ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 19.20% How can I fix this in order to change this interest rate column into float? Thank you

Comment: try `df['int_rate'] = df.int_rate.apply(lambda x: x.replace('%','')).astype(float)`

Comment: I tried your code and it gave me an error on 'float' object has no attribute 'replace', i tried another code df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1]) and the "%" is moved.       but the data type is still an object and the astype(float) cant change it, it throw me an ValueError: could not convert string to float: n